# cassandra 2.0.9: query for undefined column

Tags: cassandra, cql3, schemaless

Using Cassandra 2.0.9 CQL, how does one query for rows that *don't* have a particular column defined?  For example:

```
create table testtable ( id int primary key, thing int );
create index on testtable ( thing );
# can now select rows by thing
insert into testtable( id, thing ) values ( 100, 100 );
# row values will be persistent
update testtable using TTL 30 set thing=1 where id=100;
# wait 30 seconds, thing column will go away for the row
select * from testtable;
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
select * from testtable where NOT DEFINED thing;
```

or some such and have the row with the id==1 returned.  Is there any way to search for rows that do not have a particular column value assigned?

I'm afraid I've been through the Datastax 2.0 manual, as well as the CQLSH help with no luck trying to find an operator or syntax for this.  Thanks.

Comment: I did try select * from testtable where thing=null; but I got a "unsupported null value for indexed column thing".  Do I need to do something special when I create the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be available yet

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783